# KIND and kubectl: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: kubernetes, kind

I'm trying to use [KIND](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) to spin up my Kubernetes cluster and trying to use it with Kubectl but I'm stymied at the first hurdle

I set up a cluster using the following kind config

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  extraPortMappings:
    - hostPort: 80
      containerPort: 80
```

Then I use kubectl

```
kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

This makes sense because if I do `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
9dcd3b6fd19d        kindest/node:v1.17.11   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       127.0.0.1:44609->6443/tcp   kind-control-plane
```

What do I have to do to start the kubernetes API server and get the nodes on it?

Comment: It seems you have no contexts configured in your kubectl, or you have any older kubeconfig `~/.kube/config` which left from the previous attempt.
`kubectl config view` will show the current settings. Also, you can refer https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/#interacting-with-your-cluster

Comment: Did the comment solution from @redInk solve you issue?

Answer (score 3):

I solve this issue with `sudo chmod 0644 /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` and `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely problem and the one that usually gets me is that you don’t have a .kube directory with the right config in it. Try this:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```